Resampling DASK timeseries data
In sort I got a data frame with a Datetime index, looking something like the following
                            price       category
datetime                                           
2020-09-31 16:15:00.000000   1023.2     A
2020-09-31 16:16:00.000000   512        A
2020-09-31 16:17:00.000000   223.2      B

And im attempting to simply groupby the category, resample to months, and then calculate the mean of each month.
After a fair amount of fiddling about, I have landed on the below attempt
def per_group(df):
    return df.resample("1m").agg({"price": "mean"})

df.groupby('postcode_part').apply(per_group, meta={'price': 'float64'}).compute()

This gives me a DataFrame with each date and the mean from that date. So, something similar to
                   price
                                         
2020-09-31          1432.2321     
2020-10-31          1234.5678

Meaning, I lost the grouping by category. I feel like I been going in circles a bit in trying to recreate the following pandas grouping in dask
pandas_df.groupby('category')['price'].resample('1M').mean()

so im guessing my approach if fundamentally wrong. Can anybody point me to the right direction in how to achieve the above in dask?
